# Correlation as measure of similarity

Tags: signal-analysis, cross-correlation

Normalized correlation is used to measure how similar are two signals. I can understand similarity visually but I haven't seen a mathematical definition for the similarity of 2 signals anywhere. So I have 2 big questions that are bothering me:

1. Is there a mathematical definition for how similar two signals are?(similar in same fashion of visually similar)
2. With that definition, is there a proof that shows correlation is maximum between similar signals and not any other signal?

***EDIT:***

Okay so I thought about 1 and I have a mathematical definition for similar signals. Basically `s1` is similar to ***`s2`*** if they are proportional, that is ***`s2 = a.s1`***. So we can focus on question 2 now :). A proof that says out of all functions out there, the correlation of ***`s1`*** and ***`s2`*** is maximum only if ***`s1=k.s2`***

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation

Comment: I couldn't comment due to me low reputation, but you may find this interesting. It is called `wavelet-based semblance analysis` - [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098300407001185).It is a signal processing technique used to compare to time series signals and has a range of visual outputs.

Comment: I've read the wikipedia article. It doesn't define similarity or provide a proof why the correlation is max between 2 similar signals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you correctly noted, similarity is not a rigorously defined mathematical term. However, "distance" can be defined mathematically. Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_measure):

> In statistics and related fields, a similarity measure or similarity
>   function is a real-valued function that quantifies the similarity
>   between two objects. Although no single definition of a similarity
>   measure exists, usually such measures are in some sense the inverse of
>   distance metrics...

Here's a hand-wavy explanation, the math isn't totally precise, but hopefully it's enough to get some intuition:

Let's say we have real valued signals $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ defined on the unit interval $t \in [0,1]$. We will say that these signals are similar if the distance $||x-y||$ is small. Note that there are various choices of how to measure distance. A commonly used distance measure is the squared difference a.k.a. L<sup>2</sup> distance defined as 
$$
||x-y||^2_{L^2} \triangleq \int_0^1 (x(t)-y(t))^2 dt \ .
$$

Let's say we have three signals $x$, $y$ and $z$. Normalize all signal energies to 1 so that $\int_0^1 (x(t))^2 dt = 1,$ etc. Suppose $x$ is more similar to $y$ than $z$. This means

$$||x-y||_{L^2} < ||x-z||_{L^2}$$

or,

$$\int_0^1 (x(t)-y(t))^2 dt < \int_0^1 (x(t)-z(t))^2 dt$$

or, rearranging terms,

$$\int_0^1 x(t) y(t) dt > \int_0^1 x(t) z(t) dt \ .$$

In other words, the correlation between $x$ and $y$ is higher than that between $x$ and $z$. This shows that in order to find a "more similar" signal, maximizing the correlation is indeed the right thing to do (assuming L<sup>2</sup> distance).

Comment: That was a really insightful derivation...I tried to formulate the problem in a more precise way. Please see my edit to question.

Comment: Note that because I normalized all signal energies to 1, the constant `k` in your edited question is 1. In other words - the signal that is most similar to a given signal is the given signal itself. The maximum value of the correlation is then equal to the signal energy i.e. 1.

Comment: as far as i can tell, the math is fine.  there's nothing hand-wavy or imprecise about it.

Comment: actually the L2 norm or *"distance"* is the square root of the expression above.  but that fact does not change any of the reasoning, which is correct as is.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson thanks for the edits. I think it's a bit hand-wavy because I didn't precisely define these functions as being in the space $L^2[0,1]$. The choice of the interval $[0,1]$ is also arbitrary. I also assumed unit norm signals without much justification.

Comment: @AtulI understand why the normalizing, if they don't have same energy signals are not comparable. On the [0,1] space, that can be any space [a,b],  right?

Comment: @dandikain yes, that's the idea. Also,  you can use discrete signals, on the space $\ell^2$ instead of $L^2$ and make the same arguments by replacing the integrals by sums.